# Azure Devops can users be changed for free?

Tags: azure, devops

I have azure-devops organization (free license) and in my team already are 5 developers. Now we need to change one's developer email. Can user be deleted and added with new email address? I am not rushing to do that my self because afraid that if user will be deleted wont be able to add again. Have someone had this experience?

Answer (score 0):

> Can user be deleted and added with new email address?

As per the [Documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1692gge_zAhXtyDgGHQgmBicQFnoECAQQAw&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users&usg=AOvVaw043iBtd6CMIt89ln6k2SwV). A free License can have 5 users but not more than that so you can delete and readd users but it should be only 5

[image]

Below are the commands to add and delete the users

To Delete User

```
az devops user remove --user
                      [--org]
                      [--yes]
```

To Remove email address

```
az devops user remove --user contoso@contoso.com --org https://dev.azure.com/contoso/ --yes
```

To Add user

```
az devops user add –-email-id 
           --license-type {stakeholder}
           [--send-email-invite {false, true}]
           [--org]
```

For further information check [Delete User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-devops-cli#remove-users-from-your-organization) and [Add User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-devops-cli).

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Microsoft support. And they told me that can't delete users and add again with different email. One solution is change exsisting  account to stakeholder then add new one and set basic rights.